# VLC media player problem

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, vlc

So the controls of VLC are gone and so is the menu in the upper corner of the screen. 
I already reinstalled it two times: once with the Ubuntu Software Center and it didn't work, so I tried with terminal with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc vlc-nox
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

This way didn't work too. I am currently on Ubuntu 13.04 (64 bit version) with the proprietary Nvidia driver 313, the system is also dual-boot with Windows.
This whole thing happened today after update of the OS, as far as I know there was no problem yesterday, it must have been from the update I think.
The player itself is working (playing movies, rewind, pause), but as mentioned the menus and controls aren't displaying, as well as the context menu when right clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `~/.config/vlc` directory to remove all the personal preferences:

```
rm -r ~/.config/vlc
```

Do this while vlc is closed and you will have a brand new installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with the config folder in front of the vlc worked. I wonder why it was like that, anyways thanks again for the help :)